# Can we prevent a command from being executed for root in Linux?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, chmod

There is this script that is difficult to read and debug.

Somewhere in it, it has commands like this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /$some_var/$another_var
```

In other words, it creates a path dynamically, and then it give that path permission recursively.

However, since it needs internet connection and it downloads stuff, sometimes those variables are empty because of a bug, and this commands gets executed:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /
```

This breaks down the operating system. And we need to reinstall it again.

We're working on the script to make it better and more resilient. But, is there a way to prevent that command from being executed for the `root` user?

I mean I want this command to not be executable if the path is `/`, even for the `root` user:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /
```

Comment: Just add a condition to not run the command if `$some_var` or `$another_var` is empty.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I agree. Sanity check. But not just empty. $some_var="/////////////" is just as bad ;)

Comment: Correct. But now the OP has a clue about what to check. And maybe that scenario will never happen.

Comment: 777 is almost certainly not what you want here. At minimum it should be `ugo+rwX` instead (which will avoid marking every single file executable, which is the worst part of this) or more probably `ug+rwX` followed by `o+rX` (to avoid having things be world writable), but realistically if you at least know what users or groups will be accessing the files, you should actually be using ACLs (which have the nice additional property that you can make new files and directories under the specified path inherit them automatically).

Comment: Downloading stuff from the internet and then running root commands based on the variables? Lovely. This is about 100x worse than SQL injections! It's already root access right there! I just need to put `; rm -rf / ;` as a variable and your system is gone.

Comment: do : `sudo chmod -R 777 "/${some_var:-UNDEF}/${another_var:-UNDEF}"` : if one or both are empty, it will attempt to chmod on a non existent directory

Comment: Place `set -ue` right after your shebang at the top of your program. It will do two things: error if a variable you called does not exist (that's `set -u`), and exit your program immediately if some command fails. Alternatively you can use `${some_var:?}` to make sure `some_var` exists and is not empty. Make sure to quote your variables in case they contain spaces or other weird characters.

Answer (score 48):

If you're asking specifically about `sudo chmod -R 777 /` on Ubuntu, then you're in luck. GNU tools have an option for that: `--preserve-root`. From [the GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Treating-_002f-specially.html):

> #### 2.9 Treating `/` specially
>
> Certain commands can operate destructively on entire hierarchies.
> [...] Since there are so few legitimate uses for such a command, GNU
> `rm` normally declines to operate on any directory that resolves to
> `/`. If you really want to try to remove all the files on your system,
> you can use the `--no-preserve-root` option, but the default behavior,
> specified by the `--preserve-root` option, is safer for most purposes.
>
> The commands `chgrp`, `chmod` and `chown` can also operate
> destructively on entire hierarchies, so they too support these
> options. [...] Tradition and POSIX require these commands to operate
> recursively on `/`, so they default to `--no-preserve-root`, but using
> the `--preserve-root` option makes them safer for most purposes. For
> convenience you can specify `--preserve-root` in an alias or in a
> shell function.
>
> Note that the `--preserve-root` option also ensures that `chgrp` and
> `chown` do not modify `/` even when dereferencing a symlink pointing
> to `/`.

So, modify your script to use:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 --preserve-root /$some_var/$another_var
```

Note that I don't condone the use of `chmod -R 777`. It's extremely rare that `chmod -R 777` is absolutely necessary.

---

You can also use `set -u` to make your script treat unset variables as an error, or use [`${var:?message}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to treat specific instances of variables being unset an error:

```
$ message="Unset/empty variable not allowed"
$ sudo chmod -R 777 --preserve-root "/${some_var:?$message}/${another_var:?$message}"
bash: some_var: Unset/empty variable not allowed
```

(The default message is: `parameter null or not set`.)

Testing in a Docker container:

```
root@d9c4e4427d7a:/# chmod -R 777 --preserve-root "/${some_var:?$message}/${another_var:?$message}"
bash: some_var: Unset/empty variable not allowed
root@d9c4e4427d7a:/# some_var=/
root@d9c4e4427d7a:/# another_var=////
root@d9c4e4427d7a:/# chmod -R 777 --preserve-root "/${some_var:?$message}/${another_var:?$message}"
chmod: it is dangerous to operate recursively on '/'
chmod: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe
```

Answer (score 13):

> Can we prevent a command from being executed for root in Linux?

No.

> > Can we prevent a command from being executed from a script in Linux?

Yes. Don't use it and make your own. For instance you could create an alias fpr `chmod` with some checks on validity and have that execute `chmod`.

This is bad as it as though:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /$some_var/$another_var
```

- `sudo` does not belong inside a script.
- `777` is always bad. `750` at most when you have more than 1 user and `700` should be preferred on a solo machine.
- There ALWAYS has to be a check if both `$some_var` AND `$another_var` have a correct value. A sanity check is an important part of a script. More so if the values come from an untrusted source (like a user providing a variable through command line execution or by editing a config).

> mean I want this command to not be executable if the path is `/`, even for the root user:

The obvious answer is to add a sanity check before the command to evaluate the variables. You could also alias `chmod` to execute your own command that has a check on the values.

It has to be inside the script: a check on empty is not good enough: `$some_var="/////////////"` is just as bad ;)

Comment: "sudo does not belong inside a script". In some cases it does. More than a few times I found myself writing a script that should be executable by all users (or a particular group), but contained some command that can only be executed as root (or some other user - often user running some daemon, like apache). Using sudo inside the script (of course together with specific config file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, allowing use of that particular command only) is an obvious solution in this case. But I agree that using particularly `sudo chmod` inside a script is a bad idea.

Comment: -1 OP asks specifically about `sudo` commands and it is perfectly possible to do what he wants with that mechanism (with whitelist/blacklist/"!" operator)... and it's obvious that the best solution would be to fix (or delete...) the script in the first place, but that's not what he's asking. Reframing is not required for this question IMO, as OP is very much already working on the script.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Bash's extended test brackets `[[ ... ]]` to pre-check in an `if` statement ... The following will check if `$path` has character(s) other than forward slashes and spaces as well as resolving the path itself and it will evaluate false if either or both of the two parameters `$some_var` and `$another_var` are not set or empty or if both are all slashes or all spaces or if `$path` resolves to `/` ... Like this:

```bash
path="/${some_var:-EMPTY}/${another_var:-EMPTY}"

if [[ "$path" = *[!\ /]* && "$(realpath "$path" 2>/dev/null)" != "/" && ! "$path" =~ "EMPTY" ]]
then
  # your command using those variables here
  # chmod -R 777 "$path"
  echo "Directory is not root"
fi
```

**Notice**: Improved to address the hacker probability (*brought up by [@grok's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484755/can-we-prevent-a-command-from-being-executed-for-root-in-linux#comment2600254_1484770) ... Thank you @grok*) among other things.

Comment: That's playing cat-and-mouse with a hacker, and can't end well. How about `path=/tmp/..`?

Comment: @grok LOL ... That was meant to be an example addressing the OP not a hacker ... But very good point though and I will address it now in my answer ... You think evil, but right :-)

Comment: @grok Updated the answer ... How about now? Can you think of another evil thing that might happen? ... Many thanks

Comment: Hmmm... no obvious idea to hack it anymore :(
You're missing an "else" in the code snippet above, before `echo "Directory is not root"`

Comment: @grok That `echo …` is just a place holder for the real command `chmod -R 777 …` when the directory is actually not the system root … I couldn’t just put that one for people who might copy paste testing the code and sleep tight in the same time :-D … No `else` was/is intended there, so not missing that one … Appreciate your valuable feedback and many thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

A simple and effective way to make a critical script safer is to add [`set -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) in the beginning. This will stop execution on any error (non-zero return code from any commands except in conditions).

This doesn't magically make any commands safe, but if `$some_var` is set by a previous command, and that command fails, the script will stop instead of going further with an empty variable. The big advantage of `set -e` is that it often catches failures you might not have even thought about. The disadvantage is that you now have to make sure that every command you write succeeds. E.g. you cannot just `rm /tmp/file` to clean up a temp file that might not be there, as trying to remove a non-existent file will now stop your script.

Usually well-written scripts try to catch all obvious errors explicitly, but use `set -e` anyway to cover remaining failures.

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
# if both of the variables are not empty
if [[ -n "$some_var" && -n "$another_var" ]]
then
    # run the chmod command as intended
    sudo chmod -R 777 /$some_var/$another_var
else
    # only do this if you don't want the script to continue, but to exit with an error message
    echo "Error - exiting"
    exit
fi
```

If any of the vars could include a string of just slashes (`/` characters) you need to check for that as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the **chroot** command is intended for.

In essence, you build a tree with the needed files (binaries, settings, data) under some directory and then chroot into it.

While escaping a chroot jail is possible, it is unlikely to happen just because of a bug, it requires intent.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we prevent a command from being executed for root in Linux?

Technically, yes, once you find the exact offensive command, you can use the `!` operator to "subtract" individual commands from `ALL`.

While it is of course much better and advisable to fix your script, in this particular case, you can use that mechanism for the time being to avoid at least this one problem. Obviously this won't help you if there are other bad commands in there.

Alternatively (again, only if you were not able to fix the script itself) you could opt to remove the `ALL` from your `sudoers` file and replace it by a whitelist of all known commands the script may execute. This also would probably only make sense if the number of commands is small.

Note that this mechanism is not applicable in security contexts; as the [sudoers](https://man5.pgdp.sse.in.tum.de/sudoers.5.html) man page itself clearly states in the `SECURITY` section, this does not help whatsoever against malicious people (or against some that simply don't care). As long as a user has the `ALL`, they can always find ways to circumvent the `!` operator, often simply by renaming the command in question. But for this particular question, it's not about security and being robust against attack, but as a last line of defense against a buggy script; this might be a rare case where `!` would maybe make sense to use.